# FullCalendar: Group events by time range

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

As mentionned in the title, I'd like to group events by time range in an agendaDay-like view.

For example, I want all the events starting in the time slot [00:00 - 06:00] to be listed one below the other.

The desired result should be similar to this mock-up:

[image: Calendar mockup]

I've tried tweaking the slot duration and its label:

```
views: {
    agendaDaily: {
        type: 'agendaDay',
        slotLabelInterval: { hours: 4},
        slotDuration: { hours: 4},
        duration: { days: 7},
        buttonText: 'My View'
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: what have you tried so far? What did / didn't work?

Comment: @ADyson: I tried SlotDuration and slotLabelInterval and manipulating the CSS but no good

Comment: well at least please show what you tried. Maybe there is still a basis for a solution, and it just needs tweaking. Maybe not. But at least we will have something to start from.

Comment: @ADyson: I edited my question

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/11/ is still quite naive but probably closer to what you need. Your basic problem will always be that fullCalendar positions the events absolutely next to the real time they cover. So you won't just get a simple list. If you can live without the slots at all (after all, a 6-hour slot doesn't really say very much), you could just use the "basic" style view: https://fullcalendar.io/views/basicWeek/. Or maybe even "listWeek" would look nicer. I don't know, it depends how rigid your requirements are. Ask yourself what value these slot groupings actually give the user.

Comment: @ADyson: I fully understand your reflexion, but in fact it's the client requirement that oblige me to base my customization on the agendaDay view.
Thanks for the given example, I think I'll rather work on the basicWeek view, with a little bit tweaking it can give something close to the given mockup
One more question if it doesn't bother you, is there any alternative to FullCalendar that may give a closer result to what I need ?

Comment: I don't happen to know of any from personal experience, sorry. One thing you could do is challenge the client, and find out how much they value the specifics of the requirements. You can say "I can make it look exactly how you want but it's a lot of work and will take X time and cost $$$, or I can make it look quite similar (and show a mockup of what fullCalendar can already do) and it'll take 5 minutes and cost you $0. Then you find out if they really need it exactly like that, or they just specified that because it's the 1st thing they thought of, or they saw something else like that.

Comment: It will depend on what they need and the reasons they need it like that. Sometimes there's actually a lot of flexibility from clients if you explain the technical limitations, and you usually get more positive responses if you offer them an alternative and explain how it saves money, and point out that it has still the key features (e.g. displays events clearly, in a list, with time shown).

Comment: @ADyson Thanks a lot !